# Don't resort data.table rows

Tags: r, data.table

I am learning `data.table` so I'm very new to it's syntax.  I am trying to use the package as a hash lookup and it works well except, because of my ignorance of syntax, it reorders the rows.  I want it not to reorder the rows without sacrificing speed (i.e., the efficient way to accomplish this).  Here is an example and desired output:

```
library(data.table)

(key <- setNames(aggregate(mpg~as.character(carb), mtcars, mean), c("x", "y")))
set.seed(10)
terms <- data.frame(x = c(9, 12, sample(key[, 1], 6, TRUE)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## > terms$x
## [1] "9"  "12" "4"  "2"  "3"  "6"  "1"  "2"

setDT(key)
setDT(terms)
setkey(key, x) 
setkey(terms, x)
terms[key, out := i.y]
terms
```

This gives:

```
##     x      out
## 1:  1 25.34286
## 2: 12       NA
## 3:  2 22.40000
## 4:  2 22.40000
## 5:  3 16.30000
## 6:  4 15.79000
## 7:  6 19.70000
## 8:  9       NA
```

I want:

```
##     x      out
## 1:  9       NA
## 2: 12       NA
## 3:  4 15.79000
## 4:  2 22.40000
## 5:  3 16.30000
## 6:  6 19.70000
## 7:  1 25.34286
## 8:  2 22.40000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In `data.table`, a join `x[i]` *has* to have a key set for `x`, but it's not essential for the key to be set for `i`.
>
> NOTE: But if you don't set the key for `i`,
>
> - 1) Ensure that the columns of `i` are in the same order as the key columns of `x` (reorder if necessary, using `setcolorder`), as it doesn't join by checking for names (yet).
> - 2) It could be a tad slower (but not by much in my benchmarks).

The issue therefore is that, if you just want to do a `x[i]` join without any additional preprocessing, then `terms` has to take the place of `i` with no key set in order to get the results in the order you require.

With this in mind, we can approach this in two ways (that I could think of).

---

First method:

This one requires *no additional preprocessing*. That is we treat `key` as `x` as mentioned above - meaning it's key *has* to be set. We don't set key for `terms`.

```
setkey(key, x)
```

The first column of `terms` is also named `x` and that's the column we want to join with. So, no reordering needed here.

```
ans = key[terms]
> ans
#     x        y
# 1:  9       NA
# 2: 12       NA
# 3:  4 15.79000
# 4:  2 22.40000
# 5:  3 16.30000
# 6:  6 19.70000
# 7:  1 25.34286
# 8:  2 22.40000
```

The difference is that this is an entirely new data.table, not just assigning the column by reference.

---

Second method:

We do a little *extra preprocessing* - addition of an extra column `N` to `terms`, by reference, which runs from `1:nrow(terms)`. This basically helps us to rearrange the data back in the order required, after the join. Here, we'll consider `terms` as `x`.

```
terms[, N := 1:.N]
setkey(terms, x)
```

It doesn't matter if `key` has 'x' column set as key.. But again, ensure that `x` is the first column in `key` if it's key isn't set.. In my case, I'll set the key column of `key` to `x`.

```
setkey(key, x)
setkey(terms[key, out := i.y], N)
> terms
#     x N      out
# 1:  9 1       NA
# 2: 12 2       NA
# 3:  4 3 15.79000
# 4:  2 4 22.40000
# 5:  3 5 16.30000
# 6:  6 6 19.70000
# 7:  1 7 25.34286
# 8:  2 8 22.40000
```

Personally, since you require `terms` unsorted, I'd go with the first method here. But feel free to benchmark on your real data dimensions and choose which suits your need best.

Comment: I went with the first w/o benching b/c it's simple and was < 1 sec on 10 million terms w/ 26 key values.  Thanks for the help.